# Make height 100% of page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm experimenting with Flexbox a bit and I was wondering whether there is a property, such as flex: 1, that allows the height of an element to be 100% of the page height without adding scroll bars to scroll down. If I was to resize it, it would stick and not add scroll bars. I hope you understand. I added a fiddle with height just set at 1000px and I was hoping if any of you guys/girls would know how to set it to be 100% of the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/mL594h73/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
}

.box-1 {
flex: 1;
width: 200px;
height: 1000px;
background-color`enter code here`: #2ABB9B;
}

.box-2 {
flex: 1;
width: 200px;
height: 1000px;
background-color: #16A085;
}
```

Comment: Use VH on the div or element. 1vh = 1/100th the height of the screen. 100vh would therefore be 100% screen height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `height:100vh` in `.wrapper`  and remove default `margin` from `body`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh
}

.wrapper>div {
  flex: 1;
  width: 200px;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: #2ABB9B;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: #16A085;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the default margin from the body and add `min-height` to your parent div `wrapper` like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: not enough. you need to remove default `margin` from body

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an alternative is to set a ´position:absolute´ to get `height:100%` working properly. Also you can set `display:table` for the main container, and `display:table-cell` to containers inside to fit the `height:100%`

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.box-1 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #2ABB9B;
}

.box-2 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #16A085;
}
```

Example working: https://jsfiddle.net/mL594h73/1/